# Test HSQLDB connection used in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hsqldb

can i somehow test if my db (HSQL used) connected properly ?
Is there any possibility to mock this kind of database, to just test it, not exactly connect to it ?

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb.script
spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Configure another HSQLDB with `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test` (all in-memory) and connect to this one instead of the main db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use JUnit ? Sample code and steps below - syntax error may be there.

Configur an H2 in-memory database as a data source for tests: sample file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

Spring Boot will use these properties to automatically configure a DataSource bean.

You can define a test Entity and repository using Spring JPA ( include dependency in maven if needed)

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String value;

    // add constructors, getters, setters etc
}
```

Create Repository

```
public interface TestEntityRepository
  extends JpaRepository<GenericEntity, Long> { }
```

Now write a test class to see if connection is all ok?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class SpringBootJPAIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void givenTestEntityRepository_whenSaveAndRetreiveEntity_thenOK() {
        TestEntity TestEntity= testEntityRepository
          .save(new TestEntity ("test"));
        TestEntity  foundEntity = genericEntityRepository
          .findOne(genericEntity.getId());

        assertNotNull(testEntity);
        assertEquals(testEntity.getValue(), foundEntity.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Its ok, but why to use H2 if i already have hsqldb which is i guess similar. Your answer is ok but i got task to not change anything in db and even not connect to it but test this db.
I thought about mockito to mock this connection, any solution ?

Comment: You can keep HSQL that I am not suggesting to change. I have sample code on how to do connect to inmemory db. What I suggested is how to test db connection using JUnit and Spring boot? You can mock but will it test actual connection?

Comment: Yes, youre right, when mocked connection, testing it is without sense, thans for your time +

Comment: @cwiq Can you please accept and upvote the answer then?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

or

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true 
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```